# How would I make a Bukkit webserver?

Tags: bukkit

I am trying to start a bukkit plugin that allows you to control your server online! I am having a slight error though. I have no idea how to do that. I will write the code for the website, I just need the code to handle the http request. Please help!

Comment: Find a Java library that hosts an HTTP web server. Cool plugin idea; I considered doing something like this myself, but then Bukkit got Shrekt :(

Comment: Would something like [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bukkit/minecraft is obviously off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to make something like this. You can use `com.sun` packages, it is very useful, but `@Deprecated`. I did it like this:

```
Public class HttpProcessor {
    public HttpProcessor(MainClass plug) {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.Create(new InetSocketAddress(9090), 0);
        server.createContext("/returnstaticvalue", new RSVhandler());
    }

   static class RSVhandler implements HttpHandler {
       public void handle (HttpExchange h) throws IOException {
           h.getResponseHeaders().set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           HttpProcessor.writeResponse(h, "The static value");
       }
   }
   public static void writeResponse(HttpExchange httpExchange, String response) throws IOException {
    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
  }
}
```